# SSRS - Mail the report on Execution

Tags: ssrs-2008

Is there any way in SSRS so that I can get the Report as a mail attachment once it got executed. I am not asking about subscriptions. Please Help

Comment: with out subscriptions. this can dome by using scripting. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

There are so many options here - it depends on your scenario.  This is probably the best starting point:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522713.aspx

Comment: I was just searching to implement the mailing part in SSRS itself. Lately I achieved it by invoking the subscription job(Sql job created for each subscriptions) and Invoke the same through a query/SP.

Comment: Its good to use the built in functionality if you can - rather than reinvent the wheel.